# Laravel Exception of htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

In a Laravel 5.6 I am getting this exception:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   (View:
>   /code/admin-adc/resources/views/transactions.blade.php)

In the Controller I have

```
public function transactions($id)
{
    $raw = Deal::whereId($id)->first();

    if($raw) {
        $deal = new DealsResource($raw);
    }
    return view('transactions', compact('deal'));
} // end function
```

In the view I have

```
<div class="padded__container">
    <transactions-view
        :current_user="{{ $current_user }}"
        :dealdata="{{ $deal }}"></transactions-view>
</div>
```

In the view component I have

```
<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                deal: {}
            };
        },
        components: {},
        created() {
            this.deal = this.dealData;
        },
        props: ['current_user', 'dealData'],
        computed: {},
        methods: {},
        mounted() {}
    };
</script>
```

Comment: share the views/transactions.blade.php code where you have used the htmlspecialchars() function

Comment: Try with `$deal = new DealsResource($raw->toArray());`